# Serialization and deserialization of HashMap<MyObject, List<Integer> with Jackson

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I am currently working on a small android app that needs to be able to save/restore a range of settings via serialization/deserialization using the Jackson lib. 
For most parts it works really well and I can serialize my objects and restore them again.
Now I need to serialize/deserialize private member with the type:

```
HashMap<Model, List<Integer>>
```

Model being one of my own objects containing a bunch of simple values + getter/setter methods. 
And this is where I run into problems. It starts throwing the following error at me:

```
DataAccess: Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class com.schulz.toolie.Models.Model] at [Source: (String)"{"; line: 1, column: 1]
```

I have tried setting annotations like @JsonAnyGetter and @JsonAnySetter on the getter/setter methods along with the @JsonProperty("subscribe") on both the getter, setter and variable.

Is there any way to get around this? preferably without writing custom serialization/deserialization methods as I will get quite a few of these.

Comment: I'm confused. *What* would the generated JSON be for such a field?

Comment: maybe something like
    [ ["var1": "", "var2": 123, "var3": "xxx"], [1,4,5,7,5,4,3,3]]

Comment: First, I don't understand where would these things come from when starting with a Map. Two, that's not valid JSON.

Comment: right so it was to get you an idea of what I would guess it would look like. To me the look of the data is less important as it is not meant to be used for anything but this serialization and deserialization

Comment: Well the goal of Jackson isn't "shove whatever in it and it'll find a way to put it in JSON form". It is to convert it to a JSON form that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that Jackson has a standard for converting a Map to JSON. The keys of the map are used as the property names in the results JSON.

```
Map<String, Double> groceryPrices = new HashMap<>();
groceryPrices.put("apple", 0.25);
groceryPrices.put("orange", 0.30);
```

This naturally translates to a JSON object:

```
{
  "apple": 0.25,
  "orange": 0.30
}
```

The problem is you are using a complex object to represent a key. There is no simple method for serializing and deserializing your complex object to/from a String.

If you don't want to write custom serialization, I suggest you change your data structure. Your current structure ties together a model with it's Integers. You could fold the list of Integers into the Model object itself:

```
Map<String, Model> models; // This could map modelId -> Model which now contains the integers
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. I decided to go with an option to have the models in a separate list and then use a modelId in each of them as the key in my HashMap. Takes a bit of refactoring bit I think that will work better in the long run